# Flutter app does not pass App Store review because of blank screen

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

I am having problems with the App Store review. Trying the app on both simulator and a physical device, on both iPhone and iPad it works smoothly but every review fails because they say it doesn't start and stays on a blank page, so apparently it doesn't even get to the splash screen. On android it works fine and the review passed but on iOS I can't reproduce the problem.

I tried searching online for similar problems and I found that it could be caused by the preferred device orientation, but even leaving the default behaviour the problem still occurs. I tested both the debug and the release version on testflight but I can't reproduce the problem.

I'm using Flutter 3.16.5

Comment: Did you test on a pure ipv6 network? Did you test with no network connectivity. Did you delete the app before installing from TestFlight? Can you test by installing from TestFlight onto a device that has never had your app?

Comment: I tried everything but the ipv6 network

Comment: You most likely encounter an error in the main() function and the app cannot be started.
Put the functions in the main() function into the try-catch block and try again and follow the catch block. Your error is most likely caused by this.

Comment: Have you tried Sentry? It allows you to have a log of any uncatched exception that may happen on any device connected to internet... maybe it will provide some additional info.